# Uso correcto de forkJoin

Tags: angularjs, observable, rxjs

Estoy iterando un array y por cada value de ese array, debo consumir dos servicios.

Inicialmente lo hice consumiendo un solo servicio y me funcionó haciéndolo con un forkJoin y subscribiéndome de la siguiente forma:

```
    let infoPantallas = forkJoin(
      items.filter((e) => e.tipoobjeto == 17 && e.idpantalla).map(
        (value, index) => {
          return this.pantallasService.getpantallas(0, {id: value.idpantalla})
        }
      )
    )
    
    infoPantallas.subscribe(value => {
      value.forEach(res => {
        console.log(res.items[0]);
      })
    })
```

Ahora, lo que necesito es consumir dos servicios en el forkJoin y no sé cómo hacerlo. Intenté separados por comas pero creo que el return solo toma el primer valor.

Intenté de la siguiente forma y tampoco funcionó. Realmente no entiendo cómo funciona.

````
      items.filter((e) => e.tipoobjeto == 17 && e.idpantalla).map(
        (value, index) => {
          return [this.pantallasService.getpantallas(0, {id: value.idpantalla}), this.getInfoCamposPantalla(0, {idbloque: value.idbloque})]
        }
      )
    )```
````

Answer (score 0):

En la mayoría de los casos cuando manipulamos flujos de datos `Observable` lo mejor es dividir el flujo de cada uno de ellos para poder trabajarlos de una manera mas cómoda.

Para tu caso lo que hice fue dividir en 2 Observables el response de los servicios utilizados :

```
    let items = [{ tipoobjeto: 17, idpantalla: true }];
    let $observable1 = from(items); // Representa la llamada a un servicio
    let $observable2 = from(items); // Representa la llamada a un servicio

    let $infoPantallas = of(
      items.filter((e) => e.tipoobjeto == 17 && e.idpantalla).map(
        (value, index) => {
          return $observable1; / /Representa el this.pantallasService.getpantallas()
        }
      )
    )
    let $infoPantallas2 = of(
      items.filter((e) => e.tipoobjeto == 17 && e.idpantalla).map(
        (value, index) => {
          return $observable2; // Representa el this.getInfoCamposPantalla()
        }
      )
    )
```

Finalmente con el uso correcto de `forkJoin()` podemos emitir los valores combinados y trabajarlos de manera cómoda:

```
forkJoin($infoPantallas, $infoPantallas2).subscribe(([info1, info2]) => {
  info1.forEach(items => {
    items.subscribe(item => console.log(item.idpantalla)); // Output: true
  });
  info2.forEach(items => {
    items.subscribe(item => console.log(item.tipoobjeto)); // Output: 17
  });
});
```

Como mejora al código anterior podríamos metodizarse el filter a los items por `tipoobjeto` e `idpantalla`, para no estar repitiendo dicha lógica cada vez:

```
let $infoPantallas = of(
  items
    .filter(e => e => isCorrect(e))
    .map((value, index) => {
      return $observable1;
    })
);
let $infoPantallas2 = of(
  items
    .filter(e => isCorrect(e))
    .map((value, index) => {
      return $observable2;
    })
);

function isCorrect(item: any) {
  return e => e.tipoobjeto == 17 && e.idpantalla;
}
```

Te dejo este [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-739gey?file=index.ts) de stackblitz para que pruebes la solución.